# Typing a function that returns two different types based on optional input

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
function useSomething<T extends Element>(ref?: React.RefObject<T>) {
  const elementRef = ref ? ref : useRef(null)
  const [bb, setBb] = useState(false)

  // do something...

  return ref ? [bb] : [elementRef, bb]
}
```

So it can be called in two ways:

```
const [ref, bb] = useSomething<HTMLDivElement>()
```

or

```
const ref = useRef(null)
const [bb] = useSomething<HTMLDivElement>(ref)

// TYPE ERROR
<div className="" ref={ref}></div>
```

Here I get:

```
Type 'boolean | MutableRefObject<any>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>'.
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>'
```

How can I type the function so that the return type is always correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will not infer the return type based on the condition. You need to use overloads to get the desired effect:

```
function useSomething<T extends Element>(ref: React.RefObject<T>): [boolean]
function useSomething<T extends Element>(): [React.RefObject<T>, boolean]
function useSomething<T extends Element>(ref?: React.RefObject<T>) {
  const elementRef = ref ? ref : useRef(null)
  const [bb, setBb] = useState(false)

  // do something...

  return ref ? [bb] : [elementRef, bb]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFIDKMKMScAvnKVBCHAORSoacBQ-UvgB2GYBBEFiVdkhgALYCIDmAHgAqcJAA96IgCaE4AUQA2SEEhEwAfAAoepAFyJeMAHRkA8gCMAVkgYmrYAlK4A2r4QEBYoIgC6QqLiktLUcorK6lq6+kamFlY2DuFwEcjonj4BQTAh2NGxqInJYjASUpSyVlmqmtp61gXmltZ2jkikAPyulRheU36BwRphuPxwcGiShPBIReNkcAC8cE5w0+dTcK6UZPYi+GZmoZvbu-BRvtjEMABCvgSp3SNDoSHspBQZmIb3eAHp4XADBA4IRMkpVB5sYItjwYPgoFILldvsDIgcxjYyI0gfxGIJ+DsRHtkQBGEH2UKnWwbLbM1kRJy04FnboY7JqAASGgAsgAZAAiwAAbqNihM3nj5ISpGoDKrtmYUIRCAA5FBWE4AImt11IJxwTkYtjU8INKt59MZAvgBgATJzuSdeTh3r77SD7lNHs9XuHPuVfECozIJf0ZQrlWrDiVJqQtdcCUS4PrDWhjaaLVbbfbHc7Xe7VV7GEA)